# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken Error when creating a doorkeeper application

Tags: rails-api, doorkeeper

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm beginning with rails-api.

Right now i'm trying to add authentication through doorkeeper using resource owner password credentials.

But when im going to the /oauth/applications page to set a new app to add my frontend for exemple, i get an error about an authenticity token:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Doorkeeper::ApplicationsController#create

As it's a page implemented in the doorkeeper gem itself, isn't it suppose to work by itself?
Does any one know what's going on and how to solve it?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the forgery protection enabled by default by rails.

If you're working on an API only, my guess is that you can simply turned it off in the environment file (test/developpement/production.rb) by adding this line :

`config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false`

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's an incompatibility with **rails-api** and **doorkeeper**.

My project are being started and based on this and other things, I've chose [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) instead of [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api). It works for me!

If you can do this, I can't help you now!

tip: Enjoy with grape!

Comment: I have this problem with grape currently, since I use doorkeeper to protect my grape-api, so you can still get the error ;-) Having that said, still enjoy grape!